# Change Div order on Responsive Design

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I am creating a responsive design website.

Basically when the view port is lower than X I want to show the menu at the foot of the page.

EXAMPLE
LINK DEAD - SITE NO LONGER OWNED BY ME

IF you resize your browser window, you will notice 3 different designs (Based on end goal design rather than device types)

V1: greater than 999px, You will see Red box top left, blue box next to red box.

V2: between 600px and 999px, You will notice red box gets smaller, blue box now sits under red box

v3: Less than 600px, You will notice again red box gets smaller, blue box now yellow.

Basically, in V3, I want to make the now yellow box, sit under the green box, above the grey box

so the order goes
Red Box
Green Box
Yellow box
Grey Box

Other than the nasty hide old div, show new div hack (technique) or JS version (goes away from CSS Responsive) 
Is there a way to move this.

CSS is within the file, so view source shows everything.

Cheers

Comment: This is a common problem, flex-box is in the works though and will solve this.

Comment: The URL given redirects to MALWARE http://i.imgur.com/39Fo2gN.png

Comment: This post is from 4 years ago, I no longer own that domain.

Comment: The answer contain here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32829567/change-div-order-with-css-depending-on-device-width

Answer (score 12):

I honestly can't think of a way to do this in CSS alone, but it is easily doable in jQuery without breaking your responsive design. Your CSS doesn't need to change except to remove the margin-top from the #top-links div.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).load($(window).bind("resize", listenWidth));

    function listenWidth( e ) {
        if($(window).width()<600)
        {
            $("#topLinks").remove().insertAfter($("#content"));
        } else {
            $("#topLinks").remove().insertBefore($("#content"));
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Though the technique for reordering elements is fine, your implementation here is terrible. The most egregious issue is that you're performing the reordering operation every time `resize` is triggered, which can be dozens of times per second in IE, Safari, and Chrome.

Comment: I solved mine without using remove. `$("#mydiv").insertBefore($("#myotherdiv"))`

Answer (score 5):

I have just implemented a solution from

http://www.jtudsbury.com/thoughts/rearrange-div-order.php

that uses `display: table-header-group;` and `display: table-footer-group;`

Here is my example for two horizontal 50% width boxes that switch to right above left box on shrinking window width:

```
.box-container {
    display: table;
}

.box-50 {
    width: 50%;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 700px) {

    .box-container {
        display: block;
    }
    .box-50 {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }


    /* http://www.jtudsbury.com/thoughts/rearrange-div-order.php */
    .box-50.left {
        display: table-footer-group;
    }

    .box-50.right {
        display: table-header-group;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this Maybe Helpful

```
    @media (min-width:1px) and (max-width:599px) {
        #pageFrame {
            width:100%;

        }
        #logo {
            margin:0 auto;
            width:50px;
            height:50px;
        }
        #topLinks {
            position:absolute;
             top:250px;
            float:right;
            width:100%;
            background-color:yellow;

        }
        #content {
            position:absolute;
            top:100px;
            clear:none;
            float:left;
            width:100%;
        }
        #footer {
            position:absolute;
            top:350px;        
            clear:both;
            width:100%;
        }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bUxDE/24/)

Answer (score 2):

Flex-Box is the answer you are looking for. Check out ( this link is now broken - http://www.jordanm.co.uk/lab/contentchoreography) for a full explanation for all of Flexbox features https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Does flex-box work for all browsers? (i.e. old Android native browser etc.) ?

Comment: Flexbox is only supported in IE10 and up, and not at all on opera mini. It is supported on android 2.1 and up (see details here http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Comment: the link is dead and an answer should be able to stand on its own without an external link.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is very simple to change the order of divs in a container. Please have a look into my working HTML css code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #nav_bar{
                width:100%;
                height:50px;
                background:red;
            }
            #container{
                width:100%;
                height:500px;
            }

            #left_panel {
                position:relative;
                float:left;
                width:250px;
                border:0px solid black;
                background:#ccc;
                height:100%;
            }
            #right_panel{
                width:100%;
                background:#666;
                height:100%;
            }
            #inner_container{
                height:100%;    
            }
            .center {
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                width: 40%;
                padding-top:50px;
            }
            .data_container{
                border:1px solid black;
                float:left;
                position:relative;
                padding:10px;
            }
            #footer{
                width:100%;
                height:50px;
                background:blue;
            }
            @media all and (max-width: 700px) {
                #container {
                    width: 100%; 
                    height: 500px;
                    display: flex;
                    flex-flow: column-reverse ;
                }
                #left_panel {
                    width:100%;
                    height:200px;
                }
                #right_panel{
                    width:100%;
                    height:300px;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="nav_bar">Nav</div>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="left_panel">
                <div class="center">
                    Left Panel content
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="right_panel">
                <div id="inner_container" class="center">
                    <div class="data_container">
                        Action Item 1
                    </div>
                    <div class="data_container">
                        Action Item 2
                    </div>
                    <div class="data_container">
                        Action Item 3
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div id="footer">Footer</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to create two divs one in the footer and one in header, "display:none" the bottom one when the screen is less then X show it.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the `direction` css property.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction

What you can do is:

1. `direction: rtl;` on your parent container : `.container { direction: rtl; }`
2. reset it to normal on the direct children : `.container > * { direction: ltr; }`
3. Change the order of your divs in your HTML to display things in the right order on desktop version

And this is working on every browsers cause this property is supported everywhere (from IE 5.5...).

Answer (score 0):

using EventListener and matchMedia:

```
 //on load
 responsive_change_box_order();
 //on resize
 window.addEventListener('resize', responsive_change_box_order );

 function responsive_change_box_order() {
       if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1118px)").matches) {
           jQuery("#block-menu-block-1").remove().insertBefore(jQuery("#content"));
       }
       else{
           jQuery("#block-menu-block-1").remove().prependTo(jQuery(".region-sidebar-second .region-inner"));
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap 4, I created a simple plugin to check for the current media query breakpoint and then set it as a variable.

You can then do something like

```
  if ( xs == true ) { 
    $("#topLinks").remove().insertAfter($("#content"));
  }
```

You can get it here: https://jacoblett.github.io/IfBreakpoint/