# Bootstrap - Responsive Navbar not working properly

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 `navbars`, A and B, originally, when you shrink the browser to `max-width: 767px` B sets on top of A, `I needed A on top of B`, this was answer in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617134/how-to-move-a-navbar-with-bootstrap), I choose the `css` answer but it came with a glitch, when you click the button to show the content of the `narvars`,  `A` stays on the same place, but `B` moves below `A`, which is not the desire functionality.

To make things clearer... I'll show it graphically:

Before clicking the button to show `navbar`'s content
[image]

After clicking the button to show the `navbar`'s content
[image]

Originally `Main Menu` was on top of `Title`, this was changed with the next `CSS` class:

```
.navbar-left {
    position: relative;
    top: 88px;
}
.navbar-inner {
    position: relative;
    top: -44px;
}
```

Here's the live demo: **[click here](http://jsfiddle.net/luissanchezm86/2ucL3/3/)**

I'm open to any solution, including `jquery` over the `css` changes of navs.

**Here's my custom `CSS`:**

```
body{
    border: solid;    
}
.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.btn-group {
    float: right;
}
/*****************************************************/
/*************** LEFT NAV CUSTOM STYLES **************/
/*****************************************************/
 .navbar-inner-left {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
.navbar-left {
}
.navbar-left .nav>li {
    float:none;
}
.navbar-inner-left div>.nav-list {
    padding-left: 0;
}
.navbar-inner-left .container-fluid>.brand {
    padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
}
.navbar-inner-left {
    border: none;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #ffffff);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#ffffff), to(#ffffff));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #ffffff);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #ffffff);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #ffffff);
    border: none;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff', endColorstr='#ffffffff', GradientType=0);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0;
    box-shadow: 0;
}
/*************** RESPONSIVE STUFFF ***************/
/*************** RESPONSIVE STUFFF ***************/
/*************** RESPONSIVE STUFFF ***************/
/*****************************************************/
/*************** LEFT NAV CUSTOM STYLES **************/
/*****************************************************/
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
}
@media (min-width: 980px) {
}
@media (max-width: 979px) {
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
    .navbar-left .btn-navbar {
        margin-right: -15px;
    }
    .navbar-inner-left .container-fluid>.brand {
        float: left;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    /* BEGIN classes that make Title comes on top of Main Menu */
    .navbar-left {
        position: relative;
        top: 88px;
    }
    .navbar-inner {
        position: relative;
        top: -44px;
    }
    /* END classes that make Title comes on top of Main Menu */    
    #logo-client {
        display:none;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 480px) {
    .nav-collapse .nav>li>a, .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a {
        padding-left: 30px;
    }
    .navbar-inner-left .container-fluid>.brand {
        padding-left: 30px;
    }
    .navbar-inner-left .nav-list>.nav-header {
        padding-left: 20px;
    }
    .navbar-left .btn-navbar {
        margin-right: 26px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .nav-collapse .nav>li>a, .nav-collapse .dropdown-menu a {
        padding-left: 30px;
    }
    .navbar-inner-left .container-fluid>.brand {
        padding-left: 30px;
    }
    .navbar-inner-left .nav-list>.nav-header {
        padding-left: 20px;
    }
    .navbar-left .btn-navbar {
        margin-right: 26px;
    }
    /*.span2 {
        margin:0 auto;
        top: 100px;
        clear:none;
        width:100%;
    }
    .span10 {
        margin:0 auto;
        top:0px;
        clear:both;
        width:100%;
    }*/
}
```

**`HTML` code snippet**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span2">
            <img id="logo-client" alt="140x140" src="http://lorempixel.com/140/140/" />
            <div class="navbar navbar-left">
                <div class="navbar-inner navbar-inner-left">
                    <div class="container-fluid">   <a data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-navbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span></a>  <a href="#" class="brand">Main Menu</a>

                        <div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
                            <ul class="nav nav-list">
                                <li class="nav-header">List header</li>
                                <li>    <a href="#">Home</a>

                                </li>
                                <li>    <a href="#">Library</a>

                                </li>
                                <li>    <a href="#">Applications</a>

                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-header">Another list header</li>
                                <li>    <a href="#">Profile</a>

                                </li>
                                <li>    <a href="#">Settings</a>

                                </li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li>    <a href="#">Help</a>

                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span10">
            <div class="navbar">
                <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <div class="container-fluid"> <a data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-navbar"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></a>  <a href="#" class="brand">Title</a>

                        <div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
                            <ul class="nav">
                                <li class="dropdown"> <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown<strong class="caret"></strong></a>

                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li>    <a href="#">Action</a>

                                        </li>
                                        <li>    <a href="#">Another action</a>

                                        </li>
                                        <li>    <a href="#">Something else here</a>

                                        </li>
                                        <li class="divider"></li>
                                        <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
                                        <li>    <a href="#">Separated link</a>

                                        </li>
                                        <li>    <a href="#">One more separated link</a>

                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dropdown"> <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown<strong class="caret"></strong></a>

                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li>    <a href="#">Action</a>

                                        </li>
                                        <li>    <a href="#">Another action</a>

                                        </li>
                                        <li>    <a href="#">Something else here</a>

                                        </li>
                                        <li class="divider"></li>
                                        <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
                                        <li>    <a href="#">Separated link</a>

                                        </li>
                                        <li>    <a href="#">One more separated link</a>

                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dropdown"> <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown<strong class="caret"></strong></a>

                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li>    <a href="#">Action</a>

                                        </li>
                                        <li>    <a href="#">Another action</a>

                                        </li>
                                        <li>    <a href="#">Something else here</a>

                                        </li>
                                        <li class="divider"></li>
                                        <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
                                        <li>    <a href="#">Separated link</a>

                                        </li>
                                        <li>    <a href="#">One more separated link</a>

                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dropdown"> <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown<strong class="caret"></strong></a>

                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li>    <a href="#">Action</a>

                                        </li>
                                        <li>    <a href="#">Another action</a>

                                        </li>
                                        <li>    <a href="#">Something else here</a>

                                        </li>
                                        <li class="divider"></li>
                                        <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
                                        <li>    <a href="#">Separated link</a>

                                        </li>
                                        <li>    <a href="#">One more separated link</a>

                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul class="nav pull-right">
                                <li>    <a href="#">Link</a>

                                </li>
                                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                                <li class="dropdown"> <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown<strong class="caret"></strong></a>

                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li>    <a href="#">Action</a>

                                        </li>
                                        <li>    <a href="#">Another action</a>

                                        </li>
                                        <li>    <a href="#">Something else here</a>

                                        </li>
                                        <li class="divider"></li>
                                        <li>    <a href="#">Separated link</a>

                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="btn" type="button"><em class="icon-align-left"></em>

                </button>
                <button class="btn" type="button"><em class="icon-align-center"></em>

                </button>
                <button class="btn" type="button"><em class="icon-align-right"></em>

                </button>
                <button class="btn" type="button"><em class="icon-align-justify"></em>

                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

## **UPDATE**

Following Morpheus suggestion, now both `navbar`s behave independent, the main error is still there, here's an update:

[**Click here to check the lastest example**](http://jsfiddle.net/luissanchezm86/2ucL3/7/)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change `data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse"` to target unique class, because now you targeting two divs with same class at once.

**Example**

```
<a data-target=".unique" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-navbar">
<div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse unique">
```

Pay attention to **unique** class. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ucL3/5/)

**Update**

I have removed these styles:

```
.navbar-left {
    position: relative;
    top: 88px;
}

.navbar-inner {
    position: relative;
    top: -44px;
}
```

And it fixed the issue. I don't know if this is option for you, because menus changed stacking position. [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ucL3/12/)

Comment: You're right, it's a good practice to make them independent, it works on wider resolutions but if you go below `767px` it has the same weird behavior on `Main Menu` navbar

Comment: I would suggest to use `dropdown` menus inside `nav-collapse`

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself, shrink the `result` window to something less than `767px`, then click the button of `Main Menu` to collapse / show the contents of `Main Menu` navbar and you'll see `Title` navbar moving down...

Comment: The problem is that I needed `Title` to be on top of `Main Menu`, I had to use a little bit of `jquery`, [you can check it by clicking here](http://jsfiddle.net/luissanchezm86/2ucL3/13/). Thx for reminding me of use different actions for the responsive `navbar`