# Change order of nav items in responsive design

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-frameworks, cascade-framework

I am using [Cascade Framework](http://cascade-framework.com/) and have a simple header with a logo, select, and a link to an external site.

[My fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/6txfvvo6/2/)

The layout if fine as is in desktop mode. In responsive mode, it looks something like:

```
---------------------------------------------
Company Name
---------------------------------------------
Volvo
---------------------------------------------
Menu Here
---------------------------------------------
```

Whereas I'd like the following in responsive mode:

```
---------------------------------------------
Company Name                        Menu Here
---------------------------------------------
Volvo
---------------------------------------------
```

[These answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933356/change-div-order-on-responsive-design) suggest using flexbox or jquery. I can't use flexbox because I need ie8 support. I'd also rather not have to resort to jquery since this seems like it should be a rather straight forward css solution. Another answer on that page shows a ton of css that I've been trying to adapt to my use case and that didn't fix the issue either.

Comment: Have you tried with @media query?

Comment: wow, that Cascade Framework uses the ugliest CSS model I have ever seen :(

Comment: It is awkward....stuck w/ it for now, unfortunately ;)

Comment: @Devin : What's ugly about Cascade Framework's CSS model in your opinion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using absolute positioning?

```
.menuHere {
    position:absolute;
    text-align:right;
    right:0
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6txfvvo6/3/

Comment: I didn't even think about that. Not sure what's wrong w/ me.